# Resizing TGifimage

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8, tgifimage

I am trying to resize `TGifimage` animation using the following procedure. 
I can resize without no issues, but the quality of the animated gif is very bad.

Any idea how to enhance the quality?

Currently the animated gifs comes out black and looks corrupted.

```
procedure ResizeGif(Src, Dst: TGifImage; const newHeight, newWidth: integer);
var
  bmp, bmp2: TBitmap;
  gifren: TGIFRenderer;
  I: integer;

begin
  if (Src.Empty) or not assigned(Src.Images[0]) then
  begin
    exit;
  end;

  bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
  gifren := TGIFRenderer.Create(Src);

  try
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    bmp2.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    bmp.Width := newWidth;
    bmp.Height := newHeight;

    for I := 0 to Src.Images.Count - 1 do
    begin

      bmp.SetSize(newWidth, newHeight);

      gifren.Draw(bmp.Canvas, bmp.Canvas.ClipRect);

      bmp2.SetSize(newWidth, newHeight);

      bmp2.Canvas.StretchDraw(Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), bmp);

      TGIFGraphicControlExtension.Create(Dst.add(bmp2)).Delay :=
        gifren.FrameDelay div 10;;

      gifren.NextFrame;

    end;

    TGIFAppExtNSLoop.Create(Dst.Images.Frames[0]).Loops := 0;

  finally
    bmp.free;
    bmp2.free;
    gifren.free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this already

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no the other question was about animation issue and i have solve that by setting the resized image animation to True , this one is about the quality

Comment: We can only guess at what sizes are involved. Resizing raster images is hard. Sometimes impossible to do well. Often you need to pick the right algorithm  to fit the image data.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i totally agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I know, you simply can't do that with standard libraries and you must use e.g. [Graphics32](https://github.com/graphics32). Then you can write a simple function like below and also pick sampler, depending on what exactly you need, see [Resampling](https://web.archive.org/web/20161021134733/http://graphics32.org:80/wiki/FAQ/Resampling).

```
Class name        | Quality | Performance
------------------------------------------
TNearestResampler | low     | high
TDraftResampler   | medium  | high (downsampling only)
TLinearResampler  | medium  | medium
TKernelResampler  | high    | low (depends on kernel width)
```

Example of `TGraphicHelper.Resize`

```
procedure TGraphicHelper.Resize(const AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
var
  lBmpSource, lBmpResize : TBitmap32;
  lBmpTemp : TBitmap;
begin
  lBmpSource := TBitmap32.Create;
  try
    TDraftResampler.Create(lBmpSource);
    lBmpSource.DrawMode := dmOpaque;
    lBmpSource.Assign(Self);

    lBmpResize := TBitmap32.Create;
    try
      lBmpResize.Width := AWidth;
      lBmpResize.Height := AHeight;
      lBmpResize.Clear(clWhite32);
      lBmpResize.Draw(lBmpResize.BoundsRect, lBmpSource.BoundsRect, lBmpSource);

      lBmpTemp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        lBmpTemp.Assign(lBmpResize);
        Self.Assign(lBmpTemp);
      finally
        lBmpTemp.Free;
      end;
    finally
      lBmpResize.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lBmpSource.Free;
  end;
end;
```